# Matter and Electrical Impulses

Tags: electricity, biophysics

The human brain is composed of about 100 billion neurons; with trillions of synapses. These synapses transmit signals, which is obviously made of some sort of matter. This is what creates thought and allows the people reading this question to register the photons hitting their retina and process the information.

My question is, what are the electrical impulses within the human brain made of?
Electrons?

Since the entire brain is technically composed of atoms arranged in a highly complex pattern would that mean these electrical impulses are as well?

Comment: [Neurotransmitters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurotransmitter) - typically ions.